# How to build a package from source?

Tags: bash, makefile, build

I'm working on a Windows 7 computer at work and want to use the [libpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) package. Unfortunately, it's apparently not available for Windows, so I'm trying to configure it through Cygwin and I'm SO close. The last step is to install [snappy](http://google.github.io/snappy/) from Google. Again, not available on Windows...

My assumption (based on nothing) is that I can just download the tarball and build it from source, right? I tried that, and I think it worked? But a) I don't know how to tell, and b) if it did, I don't know how to tell `./configure` in `libpostal` to find it.

In order to build it from source, I downloaded the tarball and saved it in the folder that Cygwin reads as my home, which is `C:\cygwin64\home\brittenb\`. From there, I ran `bash autogen.sh`, which created the `./configure` that I needed. So I ran that and while some responses to the checks were no, it seemed to run fine. I then ran `make` and `make install`. Nothing seemed out of place, so my assumption is that it did what it was supposed to do. I just have no idea where to go from here.

Here is the output from `ls` after I run everything:

```
aclocal.m4              snappy.cc
AUTHORS                 snappy.h
autogen.sh              snappy.lo
autom4te.cache          snappy.o
ChangeLog               snappy.pc
compile                 snappy.pc.in
config.guess            snappy_unittest.cc
config.h                snappy_unittest.exe
config.h.in             snappy_unittest-snappy_unittest.o
config.log              snappy_unittest-snappy-test.o
config.status           snappy-c.cc
config.sub              snappy-c.h
configure               snappy-c.lo
configure.ac            snappy-c.o
COPYING                 snappy-internal.h
depcomp                 snappy-sinksource.cc
format_description.txt  snappy-sinksource.h
framing_format.txt      snappy-sinksource.lo
INSTALL                 snappy-sinksource.o
install-sh              snappy-stubs-internal.cc
libsnappy.la            snappy-stubs-internal.h
libtool                 snappy-stubs-internal.lo
ltmain.sh               snappy-stubs-internal.o
m4                      snappy-stubs-public.h
Makefile                snappy-stubs-public.h.in
Makefile.am             snappy-test.cc
Makefile.in             snappy-test.h
missing                 stamp-h1
NEWS                    testdata
README                  test-driver
```

`ls /usr/local/bin` shows nothing, but `ls /usr/local/include` shows:

```
snappy.h  snappy-c.h  snappy-sinksource.h  snappy-stubs-public.h
```

So... my question: did it work? Why does `./configure` in `libpostal` say it can't find `snappy`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this to build on Windows? If so please share :)

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. My assumption is that it's just because I don't have admin privileges on my computer, but I can't be sure about that.

Comment: I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

Check the return code from `make install` (`$?`). If it is zero, `make install` succeeded.

snappy looks like a library, so maybe it doesn't install anything in `/usr/local/bin`. The library is probably installed into `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'll check as soon as I get into the office. Assuming that `make install` did run correctly, how do I ensure that `libpostal` can find it? Do I just copy all of the files from `/usr/local/lib` to another location, and then do the same with files in `usr/local/share` et al?

Comment: libpostal automatically looks in /usr/local/lib so it should work.

Comment: My assumption, then, is that I'm just in way over my head. I thought I did everything right because `echo $?` returned `0`. I copied all of the files from the local `lib`, `include` and `share/doc` folders to the `usr/` equivalent and then tried to run `./configure` for libpostal. It all runs until the very end when it says `checking for library containing snappy_compress... no`. From what I could gather online, there should be a `libsnappy.dll.a` file that is created, in addition to `libsnappy.a`. Is that correct?

Comment: It shouldn't be ne necessary to copy things to /usr. check config.log, where a detailed error is logged

Answer (score 0):

The snappy dependency has been removed as of release 1.0.0. I made changes to the source and make and config so that it will build on MinGW.
Get it in my repository:
https://github.com/BenK10/libpostal_windows

Note that this is not the complete source since not everything had to be changed. I would suggest merging my changes with the official libpostal distribution to make sure you've got everything. Also, there are some extra `DLLEXPORT`s in some source files that I haven't removed yet, and the part in the Makefile that builds the executables like address_parser.exe was removed because some porting is necessary to build those programs on Windows. You can write your own using the DLL you'll get in the Windows build and the original source as a reference.